# iter with foreach

Tags: qt, foreach, iterator

I iter for a QList with while with this code:

```
QList<Job> jobsList;

jobsList = job.getJobs(650, 654);
QListIterator<Job> iterJobs(jobsList);

while(iterJobs.hasNext())
{
    job = iterJobs.next();
    qDebug() << "IdJob " << job.jobId();
    qDebug() << "jobType " << job.jobType();
}
```

and all fine but How can I to make whith foreach?

Thanks you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (Job const& job, jobsList) {
  qDebug() << "IdJob " << job.jobId();
  qDebug() << "jobType " << job.jobType();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (Job job, jobsList)
{
  qDebug() << "IdJob " << job.jobId();
  qDebug() << "jobType " << job.jobType();
}
```

Comment: This will create a copy of each job in the list, which could be a problem.